# ncc build fails after upgrade of pg-promise to 10.3.1

Tags: webpack, typescript-typings, pg-promise, zeit-ncc

Our [ncc](https://github.com/zeit/ncc) build (version `0.18.5`) fails after upgrading [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) from `8.7.5` to `10.3.1`:

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset' in ...
```

The issue occured after we added this import statement:

```
import { IConnectionParameters } from 'pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset';
```

The strange thing about the pg-promise lib is that it has 2 `d.ts` files ([github-link](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/typescript)):

[image]

Maybe that is fine, I've just not seen this before.
Most other libs either have one `d.ts` file per `js` file, or a single `.d.ts` file with all typings for the whole lib.

In the `package.json` of the lib, it only mentions one of the typings:

```
  "typings": "typescript/pg-promise.d.ts",
```

When we build the project the `main.js` output contains a require for `pg-subset`:

```
module.exports = require("pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset");
```

This `main.js` file is then passed to `ncc build` which causes the error.

I am a bit lost here, because I don't have too much experience with webpack and module systems: But I think that requiring `pg-subset` will fail, because there is no related js file, right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 14.03.2021

I think we should have used a [type-only-import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) to fix the issue:

```js
    import type { IConnectionParameters } from 'pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset';
```

Our project has already changed a lot, so I can't verify.

## ORIGINAL

I came up with a **nasty quick-fix** to make the ncc-compilation work again.

In my project I add a file `pg-subset.ts` which only reexports the used interface/s:

```js
import { IConnectionParameters as IConnectionParametersOrig } from 'pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset';

/**
 * this file is a quick-fix for the ncc build
 */
export type IConnectionParameters = IConnectionParametersOrig;
```

In all other files, I change the imports to use this project-file (instead of `pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset`).

Then the compilation works - but I don't understand why:
e.g. now we still import `pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset` (once in the new project `pg-subset.ts` file).
But this time the `main.js` file does not include this line anymore:

```
 module.exports = require("pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset");
```